# How to draw letters/symbols using canvas and validate them?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, alphabet, handwriting

I want to achieve something like this:
[image: Example of what i would like]
The application will put a background with the letter, and users will draw over it **tracing the indicators with strokes**. The main thing is to somehow **validate the strokes, and its order and direction.**

I've tried with the Gestures library but it is imprecise, and I haven't found enough helpful information about Canvas. I'm not searching for a full response, just some kind of clue or tutorial to start with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you have any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that with RN:

1. Open Figma and draw a path like this number 5 (it must be only a line)

```html
<svg width="52" height="65" viewBox="0 0 52 65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M52 1C52 1 32 1.00002 25.5 3.00006C19 5.0001 16.5 17.5 16.5 17.5C13.886 26.9226 29.1811 32.3091 36 41C42 48 29 65 16.5 63.5C8.65327 61.8949 5.49592 59.4015 1 53.5" stroke="#FF0000"/>
</svg>
```

2. Get the points and the angles with the library [svg-path-properties](https://github.com/rveciana/svg-path-properties) to get the length and all the point of the line (x,y)
3. Draw the SVG in the screen. Draw a touchable point. If the user move that point you need to calculate the current position with the array of points (x,y)[] if it match, you can draw the percent of the line that the user moved with his/her finger.

In order to do it I used [strokeDashoffset](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/DwVLpj):

```
import Svg, { Path } from 'react-native-svg';
const PathAnimated = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);
strokeDashoffset={animationsValue[index].strokeLenght}
strokeDasharray={`${pathData[index].length}, ${pathData[index].length}`}
```

I don't know if someone has a better approach. I figured out this solution.